# How to remove html tags with newline added

Tags: java, html, jsoup

The following snippet accomplishes fetching the content of the website and split the code with a html tag.

```
try {
      connection =  new URL("https://hackpad.com/ep/pad/static/HUAzLPpAUWc").openConnection();
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
      scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
      content = scanner.next();

    }catch ( Exception ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    String[] output = content.split("</p>");
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

    for(String content2:output){
        result.append(content2);
        result.append("\n");
    }
    System.out.println(result); /* First print out */

    String parsed = Jsoup.parse(result).text();
    System.out.println(parsed); /* Second print out */
```

The first print out actually output the format with what I wish to have.

However, after running Jsoup.parse(result);
all newline delimiter have been removed, which makes the second print out
did not meet my expectation.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format the content, why not simply do the following?

```java
URL url = new URL("https://hackpad.com/ep/pad/static/HUAzLPpAUWc");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(url.openStream());
sc.useDelimiter("\\A");
String parsed = Jsoup.parse(sc.next()).outerHtml();
System.out.println(parsed);
```